If we include lags of the dependent variable on the RHS of our regression of Y_t on X_t, why we not have spurious regression

So, assuming X,Y are I(1), only (7) could be spurious right? Why can (8) and (9) not be spurious? Isn't there still a common stochastic trend shared between X_t and Y_t?
